# Почему некоторые параметры метода нужно ставить раньше других?

Tags: java, spring

Собственно столкнулся с проблемой, на решение которой потратил много времени - [Нет редиректа после ошибки валидации Spring boot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1483572)

Поясните почему так и с чем это связано? А то не хочется в следующий раз тратить два дня на решение такой ерунды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобный вопрос на основном SO: [Why does BindingResult have to follow @Valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887780/)

Такой порядок обусловлен тем, что в обработчике запросов контроллера потенциально может быть несколько объектов, для которых требуется валидация, то есть, помеченных аннотацией `@Valid`.  Соответственно, для каждого такого объекта понадобится свой экземпляр `BindingResult`, и вполне логично, чтобы эти объекты находились рядом.

Сама валидация выполняется в методе [`org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor::resolveArgument`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b81a291c8548d6cf6285ef18b6e38abeb7189025/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java#L126):

```java
public final Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, @Nullable ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            NativeWebRequest webRequest, @Nullable WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
// ....
        if (binder.getBindingResult().hasErrors() && isBindExceptionRequired(binder, parameter)) {
            throw new BindException(binder.getBindingResult());
        }
// ...
}
```

И соответственно в методе [`isBindExceptionRequired`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b81a291c8548d6cf6285ef18b6e38abeb7189025/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java#L442) проверяется, что следующий за данным параметром объект НЕ является экземпляром интерфейса `Errors`, от которого унаследован интерфейс [`BindingResult`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html), то есть, НУЖНО выбросить соответствующее исключение:

```java
    /**
     * Whether to raise a fatal bind exception on validation errors.
     * @param parameter the method parameter declaration
     * @return {@code true} if the next method parameter is not of type {@link Errors}
     * @since 5.0
     */
    protected boolean isBindExceptionRequired(MethodParameter parameter) {
        int i = parameter.getParameterIndex();
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = parameter.getExecutable().getParameterTypes();
        boolean hasBindingResult = (paramTypes.length > (i + 1) && Errors.class.isAssignableFrom(paramTypes[i + 1]));
        return !hasBindingResult;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ещё и узнал, что нужен свой BindingResult для каждого объекта подвергающегося проверки.

Comment: Еще один интересный ответ по теме: Как наличие `BindingResult` влияет на тип исключения [Presence of `BindingResult` method parameter determines exception thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69692047/13279831)